# Angular8 : ng run => 'Project target does not exist.' when using i18n

Tags: json, angular, angular8, angular-i18n

Based on those tutorials :
https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/angular-internationalization-i18n-multi-language-appand https://medium.com/@ismaestro/angular-7-example-app-with-angularcli-angular-universal-i18n-official-firebase-66deac2dc31e
I'm trying to build and use an Angular 8 app using i18n as internationalisation system.

However, when I try to run `npm build:ssr` (cfr. below), I get `An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist.`

Here, the angular.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "boilerplate": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "en": {
                            "outputPath": "dist/browser/",
                            "baseHref": "/",
                            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
                            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
                            "i18nLocale": "en",
                            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
                            "assets": [
                                {
                                    "glob": "**/*",
                                    "input": "src/assets/",
                                    "output": "/assets/",
                                    "ignore": [
                                        "base/*",
                                        "css/*",
                                        "js/*"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "glob": "**/*",
                                    "input": "src/assets/base",
                                    "output": "/"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "fr": {
                            "outputPath": "dist/browser/",
                            "baseHref": "/fr/",
                            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
                            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
                            "i18nLocale": "fr",
                            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
                            "assets": [
                                {
                                    "glob": "**/*",
                                    "input": "src/assets/",
                                    "output": "/assets/",
                                    "ignore": [
                                        "base/*",
                                        "css/*",
                                        "js/*"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "glob": "**/*",
                                    "input": "src/assets/base",
                                    "output": "/"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "production-en": {
                            "assets": [
                                {
                                    "glob": "**/*",
                                    "input": "src/assets/",
                                    "output": "/assets/",
                                    "ignore": [
                                        "base/*",
                                        "css/*",
                                        "js/*"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "glob": "**/*",
                                    "input": "src/assets/base",
                                    "output": "/"
                                }
                            ],
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputPath": "dist/browser/",
                            "baseHref": "/",
                            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
                            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
                            "i18nLocale": "en",
                            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
                        },
                        "production-fr": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputPath": "dist/browser/fr/",
                            "baseHref": "/fr/",
                            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
                            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
                            "i18nLocale": "fr",
                            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "boilerplate:build:production-en"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "fr": {
                            "browserTarget": "boilerplate:build:production-fr"
                        },
                        "en": {
                            "browserTarget": "boilerplate:build:production-en"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "boilerplate:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "scripts": [],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "boilerplate-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e",
            "sourceRoot": "e2e",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "boilerplate:serve"
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "boilerplate",
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "prefix": "app",
            "styleext": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
            "prefix": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

and a part of the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "lint": "ng lint boilerplate",

        "build:prod:en": "ng build --configuration=production-en",
        "build:prod:fr": "ng build --configuration=production-fr",
        "build:server:prod:en": "ng run boilerplate:server:production-en",
        "build:server:prod:fr": "ng run boilerplate:server:production-fr",
        "build:library": "ng build ngx-example-library",
        "build:client-and-server-bundles": "npm run build:prod:en && npm run build:prod:fr && npm run build:server:prod:en && npm run build:server:prod:fr",
        "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
        "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/server"
    },
```

As previously explain, I would like to successfully run my Angular application with i18n. But the error message is:

> [error] Error: Project target does not exist.
>      at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget (/Users/user$
>      at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (/Users/user/Desktop/Boilerplate/boilerpla$
>      at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (/Users/user/Desktop/Boilerplate/boiler$
>      at RunCommand.run (/Users/user/Desktop/Boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modu$
>      at RunCommand.validateAndRun (/Users/user/Desktop/Boilerplate/boilerplat$
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:43:7)
>      at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:11)
>      at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
>      at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:826:3)

If someone already had the same issue and could explain me what I'm doing wrong ? Thx

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you by any chance fix it?

Comment: No unfortunately, I did not find any way to fix it. For the moment, I only develop my project in dev and I'll retry in production. Maybe, this is the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this. The problem is:

1) you are missing `architect` config in `angular.json` file.

2) There is a problem at your `browserTarget`. The target must point to the project, not to Angular.

[image]

1) Please add these line to `angular.json file => project => {{your project name}} => achitect: (remember to replace`"{{project name}}"` to your project name)

```
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/"{{project name}}"/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": ""{{project name}}":build",
            "serverTarget": ""{{project name}}":server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": ""{{project name}}":build:production",
              "serverTarget": ""{{project name}}":server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": ""{{project name}}":build:production",
            "serverTarget": ""{{project name}}":server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
```

2) Make sure you have `@nguniversal/express-engine` and `@nguniversal/builders` in your `package.json`:
`npm i @nguniversal/express-engine @nguniversal/builders -D`

Comment: I changed the file , and still have the error any other suggestion ? or you just copy and paste the solution? from a forum

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it using below command:

```
ng add @ionic/cordova-builders
```

Source: [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-build-android-throwing-error-in-ionic-6-project/221213/2)

Comment: I new versions of angular npm install @ionic/cordova-builders

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my fix was to add the "server" information.
because this line

"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run ngkol:server:production",

this is trying to run ng run ngkol:server:production <<<

```
"projects": {
    "ngkol": {
        "projectType":  "application",
        "schematics":   {},
        "root":         "src",
        "sourceRoot":   "src",
        "prefix":       "app",
        "architect": {

            //2019-08-23 here goes your other info
            // build, serve,extract-i18n, options, lint, e2e, 

            "server": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist/server",
                    "main": "src/main.server.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "fileReplacements": [{
                            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
```

here my app running https://www.supercolegas.com/soon

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
"server": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
    "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"  -------- Try to Replace tsconfig.server.json by tsconfig.app.json -------------
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my project name was slightly different from the name of my working directory.
Because of this, when I wrote in the 'project name' as this answer advised, I was writing in the name of my project's directory and not the name of the project itself.

The name of the project can be confirmed in the `angular.json` file in the `projects` object.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue doing `ng add @angular/pwa` and solved by adding the project name: `ng add @angular/pwa --project my-project-name-as-stated-in-angular.json-file`