# ionic cordova build android throws error: Project target does not exist

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, build

When I run ionic cordova build android, it throws this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist.
```

I found this answer but it doesn't work for me:
[Angular8 : ng run => 'Project target does not exist.' when using i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111480/angular8-ng-run-project-target-does-not-exist-when-using-i18n)
I can't find error in my project's name, and I change angular.json.

This is my angular.json:

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "i4all": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/i4all",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/custom.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js",
              "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/i4all/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "i4all:build",
            "serverTarget": "i4all:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "i4all:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "i4all:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "i4all:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "i4all:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "i4all:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "i4all:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "i4all:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/custom.scss"
                        ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "i4all:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "i4all:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "i4all"
}
```

This is my package.json:

```
    "name": "i4all",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
```

Someone can help me? Thank you so much.
Ana.